# How do I Install Fedora using CDs?

Tags: linux, installation, fedora

I'm trying to install Fedora so that I can run Amahi Home Server, my system wont boot from a DVD and I'm now sure how to install using CDs or USB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you boot up the [installable LiveCD](http://fedoraproject.org/get-fedora) (top 'download now' button) there will be a desktop icon 'Install to hard disk' - double click it and the graphical installer will start.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it, one question, when in the installation process, am I able to add any additional software repositories? I need to be able to because the Amahi installation requires it (I think).

Comment: I think the LiveCD install just copies the CD to the hard drive in more or less a single step - you would have to customise the repositories after booting into it.

Comment: The LiveCD installer wont run, I hit "Install to hard drive" and nothing happens, could this happen because there isn't enough memory? There is 389 MB of memory on the system.

Comment: OK, it may be worth trying the net installer then: go to the 'All downloads page' http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-all and try the Network Install CD.  This will download all the packages from the repos so you need an active net connection during the install.  Alternatively, you could download the 6 CD install set.

Comment: I have been trying the CD set approach, The V12 doesnt work right, the V9 kind of does, I can install but I cant add the Amahi repository, it tells me to put in the CD 1 and It's already in the drive, I put it back in the drive and it wont accept it. So I try and install the repository after I install it, on the Amahi site it says to upgrate to 4.5 but I'm not sure how.

Comment: 4.5 is a CentOS version number, so I don't think that applies.  Did you do the install steps from http://wiki.amahi.org/index.php/Self-install-existing

Comment: I'm trying to do them, it says to run yum -y install fedora-release
 and when I do it gives me an error of some sort like MD5 chucksum failed. By the way, thanks so much for helping me!

Comment: OK, it may be because Fedora 9 isn't supported any more (by Fedora or Amahi).  Did you not manage to get F12 installed at all?  I would recommend trying to get F12 installed first, without worrying about the Amahi stuff, then, if there's still a problem, as specifically about the Amahi setup in another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can install from the Live-CD available at http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora